# Oneline population of dictionary from array in Python

Tags: python

I need to populate dictionary from array. I've done in three lines and i'm trying to do it shortest as it can be. Is there way how to populate it in single line?

```
a = [['test',154],['test2',256]]
d = dict()
for b in a:
    d[b[0]] = b[1]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just `dict` :)

```
>>> a = [['test',154],['test2',256]]
>>> dict(a)
{'test': 154, 'test2': 256}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just do dict(a) or dict([['test',154],['test2',256]]).

Answer (score -1):

L = [['test',154],['test2',256]]

In Python 3.x:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in L}
```

In Python 2.x:

```
d = dict([(k,v) for k,v in L])
```

Comment: This is a poor solution compared to the others (the second one just changes the individual lists to tuples, which is unnecessary).  Also, the *'s are a syntax error here in both cases (just drop them).  The dictionary comprehension also separates elements with `:`, not `,`.